# CREATE DATABASE através de um script em PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Como eu poderia criar um banco de dados cada vez que por exemplo um usuário, no caso, uma empresa se cadastra-se no meu sistema web? Tipo, hoje, a única coisa que eu tenho são os dados de acesso administrativo ao FTP e os dados do banco de dados como host, porta ...

Como poderia dentro de uma interface administrativa criar um banco completo para um cliente desde o CREATE DATABASE? Quais são os requisitos necessários e no que o serviço de hospedagem poderia atrapalhar este procedimento?

Esta curiosidade me surgiu pelo seguinte fato: uma empresa como `Conta Azul` por exemplo tem todo um sistema administrativo financeiro e imagino que para cada cliente seja instalado um novo banco com um dump novinho só com as tabelas mas não tenho ideia de como isso é feito.

No caso, se cada cliente realmente tivesse um banco de dados pessoal e que esse banco de dados fosse criado através de um simples cadastramento de informações pessoais e jurídicas, como chegar ao resultado esperado sem ter que acessar a hospedagem ou o phpmyadmin ou qualquer **facilitador**.

Comment: Primeiro: Não é necessário criar um novo dump. Se você prevê nos seus relacionamentos que haverá uma entidade "Cliente" você pode normalizar seu banco para isso. Segundo: Em qualquer SGBD decente você pode criar bases via SQL script, basta se conectar com um login com as devidas permissões. Não acredito que hospedagem (em especial compartilhadas) permitam essa abordagem

Comment: Era mais ou menos nisso que eu gostaria de chegar. @jean então hospedagens compartilhadas provavelmente e certamente não irão permitir tal ação?

Comment: Provavelmente seria necessário uma hospedagem com um servidor dedicado mas o melhor lugar para perguntar é nas próprias empresas de hospedagem (lembre-se de que elas querem vender o serviço). Mas o ponto central no comentário é que a sua abordagem pode não ser a correta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o seu usuário tiver grant de create database você consegue normalmente executar como o exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$sql = 'CREATE DATABASE my_db';
if (mysql_query($sql, $link)) {
    echo "Database my_db created successfully\n";
} else {
    echo 'Error creating database: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
}
?>
```

**Claro que o mais correto seria trabalhar com a modelagem correta do banco para utilizar o mesmo banco para várias empresas.**